# Return array from callback function

Tags: node.js

After a few hours of thinking and googleing, I seem to be unable to find a solution to this stupid simple problem!

I'm trying to a create an array of JSON objects in order to insert them into DB. But due to Async aspect of Nodejs it has become a little bit complicated.

What I have:

```
function foo (arg) {
    request({url: arg}, function(err, response, results){
        var chunk = [];
        var r = JSON.parse(results);
        (r.bar).forEach(function(item){
            geocoder.reverse({lat: item.lat, lon: item.lng}, function(err, res){
                chunk.push(res[0].formattedAddress;
            });
        });
        console.log(chunk); \\ This is eventually empty!
        insertData(chunk); \\ useless due to chunk being empty!
    });
```

I was wondering how could I make this happen (construct an array and insert it into DB)?

I'm desperate please help.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend installing the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module, as its invaluable for node.js

First:

```
npm install --save async
```

Then:

```
var async = require('async');

function foo (arg) {
    request({url: arg}, function(err, response, results){
        var r = JSON.parse(results);
        async.map(r.bar, function eachItem (item, cb) {
            geocoder.reverse({lat: item.lat, lon: item.lng}, function(err, res){
                cb(null, res[0].formattedAddress);
            });
        }, 
        function done (err, result) {
            console.log(result); \\ this will be your ordered array
            insertData(result); \\ no longer useless!
        });
    });
```

Comment: Nice minimalistic solution even though I had tried Async, but didn't really think `.map()` could that much different from `.forEach()`. Thanks :)

Comment: .forEach() will iterate, but .map() iterates and ensures the order. Glad it worked! Async calls can be a bugger!

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the `geocoder.reverse` function to finish for each `r.bar` - create a counter, increment on each complete call, then when the final call is done, `insertData`!

```
function foo (arg) {
    request({url: arg}, function(err, response, results){
        var chunk = [];
        var r = JSON.parse(results);
        var totalCalls = r.bar.length;
        var completedCalls = 0; 

        (r.bar).forEach(function(item){
            geocoder.reverse({lat: item.lat, lon: item.lng}, function(err, res){
                chunk.push(res[0].formattedAddress); //missing ) here in your code
                completedCalls++;
                if (completedCalls == totalCalls) {
                    insertData(chunk);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Just a note with this method, you will lose the order of the data (which may, or may not matter.)

Comment: @GeorgettePincin -- True - which I should assume is important (it always is in the end) - an async module would definitely work best here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using promises to manage the async operations and retain order of multiple results:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var requestAsync = Promise.promisify(request);
var geocoder.reverseAsync = Promise.promisify(geocoder.reverse);

function foo(arg) {
    return requestAsync({url: arg}).spread(function(response, results) {
        var r = JSON.parse(results);
        return Promise.map(r.bar, function(item) {
            return geocoder.reverseAsync({lat: item.lat, lon: item.lng}).then(function(res) {
                return res[0].formattedAddress;
            });
        });
    });
}

foo(something).then(function(addresses) {
    // addresses will be an array of addresses
    insertData(addresses);
}, function(err) {
    // some error occurred
});
```

Here's an explanation for how it works:

1. Load the bluebird promise library
2. Create promisified versions of the two async functions used here and give them the "Async" suffix to distinguish them.
3. Call `requestAsync()` and use `.spread()` instead of `.then()` to more easily separate out the two values returned
4. Use `Promise.map()` to iterate the array of data for us and return a single promise that represents all the sub-promises so we know when all the geocoder operations are done.
5. Inside the `Promise.map()` iterator callback, call `geocoder.reverseAsync()` and use `.then()` to access the result.
6. Reach into the `geocoder` result to return the `formattedAddress` which will become the returned value from each promise in `Promise.map()`
7. Then, when calling `foo()` use `.then()` to set up your success and error handlers.  In the success handler, you can access the array of addresses in order.

---

FYI, if you are concerned about running into rate limiting issues about how many simultaneous geocoder calls you may have running at the same time, you can add a concurrency option to `Promise.map()` like this:

```
        return Promise.map(r.bar, function(item) {
           ...
        }, {concurrency: 3});
```

Comment: Indeed the neatest solution