# A better way to resolve callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

What I am trying to do is
1) Fetch list of available databases.
2) Fetch list of collections present in each of these databases.

And do both these things in a same API call.

I am using MongoDB driver for Node. (`require('mongodb');` not mongoose)

I can successfully get the list of databases using

```
var adminDb = db.admin(); // db is the instance of my MongoDb server
adminDb.listDatabases(function(err,dbs){
    //dbs contains information of available databases. 
}
```

Now inside this callback function. I take each database name and fetch it's collections. Like

```
exports.getDatabaseList = function(req, res) {
    var adminDb = db.admin();
    adminDb.listDatabases(function(err,dbs){
        if(err){
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            var result = dbs.databases.filterArray('local'); // This will remove the element that has name 'local'. We don't need that shit.
            var len = result.length-1;
            var count = 0;
            var check = len*((len+1)/2); // Arithmetic progresion for the number of databases available.

            for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                var dbName = result[i].name;

                getCollectionsForDb(dbName, i, function(collections, index){
                    result[index].collections = collections;
                    count+=index;
                    if(count === check){
                        res.json({content:result});
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
};

unction getCollectionsForDb(dbName, index, callback){
    var _db = db.db(dbName);
    _db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, items) {
        test.ok(items.length >= 1);
        callback(items, index);
    });
}
```

As you can see, I am looking over the results (list of available databases) and fetching it's collections and then adding them to response object.

Since I am making async call from the loop, there is no reliable way to determine if all the callbacks are returned.
So I am maintaining a variable `check` which is an arithmetic progression of `length - 1` of results array.
I have also constructed a closure wherein I pass current index in the loop and when return the same index to the calling function.
When the control comes back in calling function, I add this index to the `count` variable.
So when the value of count equals check, that is how I come to know that all the callbacks are returned and it is now safe to send the response back to the client.

However genuis this makes me feel, there is still a bug in the back of my head that this is not a right way to do it and there has to be a better way to keep track of return of callbacks that are being called in a loop (for lack of better words and terminologies)

So, my question is, is there a to do this in a more elegant and clean way? And can this be done without the awesomeness of arithmetic progression? :D

This is fine for 10 15 entries but what if I have a server that has 1000s of databases?

I also know that I can fetch the list of collection later when user selects the database from the list.
My main question is about managing callbacks and not about design of current code.

Comment: 1000s of databases?  Looping will be O(n), so the more you have the longer it'll take.

Comment: npm install async module, I actually answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216138/return-array-from-async-function/32216268?noredirect=1#comment52335559_32216268

Comment: Where are the promises in this code?  Or are you asking how to design this using promises?

Comment: @duffymo : Yes :D Just a hypothetical situation. My main questions about managing promises and not about the environment. :D haha

Comment: @jfriend00 : Pardon my jargons and sorry for not being clear enough. What I mean by the word `promise` is that a function that will return the output sometime in future. I am not referring to any library here. :)

Comment: Promises can certainly be used here, as can the async library, but whether either is "cleaner" is of course up to your own opinion.

Comment: "I am not referring to any library": well, you should be and also using them to properly handle async execution and avoid callback hell...

Comment: @GeorgettePincin : Thank you. :) What I want to know is what is it that async library does internally. I know I can do this using libraries like that.

Comment: You could read the source code for that module...it is quite powerful and resolves a bunch of issues (such as ordering) for you. Worth knowing, for sure, and if you know it well enough, you could contribute!

Comment: And why is there a downvote? Please elaborate. :)

Comment: If you use the harmony flag, you don't need a library to use Promises.

Comment: The question IS a bit unclear, since you used the word "Promise" but actually meant "Callback" it seems. Promise is one of a few possible solutions.

Comment: If you're going to use the term Promises, then people are going to think you're talking about the [actual standardized thing called Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).  If you don't mean that, then please edit your title and question to use a different term.  Otherwise people really have no idea what you're asking.  Your code would benefit greatly from using the actual Promises builtin to many systems now or available via a library.

Comment: Edited. :) Will take a look into promises as well.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the excellent async library (https://github.com/caolan/async) to manage collections of callbacks using the async `map` function.

But as you're specifically asking about an implementation using promises, I'd recommend using a library that has built-in support for arrays of promises.

Here is an example using the "when" library (https://github.com/cujojs/when):

```
when.map(dbs.databases, getCollectionsForDb).done(function(collection) {
    // use your results here  
    console.log(collection);
});

function getCollectionsForDb(db){
    return when.promise(function(resolve, reject)) {
      db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, items) {
         if (err || items.length == 1) {
              reject("describe your error here");
         }
         resolve(items);
      });
});
```

What this code does is take a collection of database objects, passes each one of those databases to a function (`getCollectionsForDb`) which returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). This generate an array of promises, and when all of the promises have been resolved (the asynchronous computation is complete, and the result of the asynchronous operation is ready) the when library invokes the callback where you can then utilize the collection of results (in this example dumping it into the console).

Comment: You should not forget to `reject` with `err`ors.

Comment: True, I added that to the example. If I was a perfectionist, I'd add timeout handling as well.